# Node mssql complete stacktrace

Tags: node.js, node-mssql

Why don't i get a stacktrace pointing to the excution point of my file

```
const sqlSelect = "error";
 
const result = await sql.query(sqlSelect);
```

result:

```
    err = new RequestError(err, 'EREQUEST')
          ^

RequestError: Could not find stored procedure 'error'.
    at handleError (...\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:384:15)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Connection.emit (..\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1048:18)
    at RequestTokenHandler.onErrorMessage (...\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\handler.js:365:21)
    at Readable.<anonymous> (...\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:26:33)
    at Readable.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at next (node:internal/streams/from:98:31) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this in the documentation

> IMPORTANT: Always attach an error listener to created connection.
> Whenever something goes wrong with the connection it will emit an
> error and if there is no listener it will crash your application with
> an uncaught error.

So i did a general

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  //Error handeling
});
```